# How to remove phone number link on Iphone?

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have mobile site which have Simple **Span** having Phone number in it.

```
<span class="order1-button">999-120-9191</span>
```

Problem: when i open my page in iphone it have link on phone number. When i click on it option come to call.

**How to remove it??**

This is link of [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SbU3/). When you open it on iphone you also find it.

On other device button is simple without link which i need.

Comment: Is this in a `UIWebView` or mobile Safari?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a meta tag to your page header to prevent mobile safari turning telephone numbers into links

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`dataDetectorTypes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/dataDetectorTypes) to tell the web view what links to ignore.

```
webview.dataDetectorType = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDataDetectorTypes) for all the types.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text-decoration:none in that class also.

Comment: We are not joking here.

Answer (score -1):

Remove text decorations.

```
<span text-decorations="none" class="order1-button">999-120-9191</span>
```