# How to remove a auto hyperlinked phone number from Microsoft Edge

Tags: web, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

I have time stamps on a web application in the form of

## 1 2015-08-06 15:16:54

which keeps getting decorated by Microsoft Edge browser as phone number links. I do not want this. Apparently, this is a 'tel' protocol and clicking on it will try to open whatever application is configured to work with the 'tel' protocol. I know there is a meta tag you can add to pages to prevent them being decorated as such on iOS devices, but how would I do this on the Microsoft Edge browser?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution that works for iOS devices also works for Microsoft Edge.

Adding the meta tag,

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

will prevent the DOM document from being modified when parsed by the browser.

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html
and
[How to remove phone number link on Iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130778/how-to-remove-phone-number-link-on-iphone)

MSDN reference link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265018(v=vs.85).aspx