# Microsoft Edge creates link that calls Skype for Business when clicked

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, microsoft-edge, skype-for-business

I would like to ask on how to remove this hyperlink in Microsoft Edge whereby it calls Skype for Business whenever it is clicked. I cannot find in the settings on how to remove it.

Below is the sample screenshot for your reference.

[image: When the user clicks on the hyperlink, it will call the Skype Lync application]

Any help would be appreciated here as I am currently new with this environment.

Here is the simple code behind of this html page.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p>Ishijima Domon 3 - 1234567 </p>
   </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a auto hyperlinked phone number from Microsoft Edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867068/how-to-remove-a-auto-hyperlinked-phone-number-from-microsoft-edge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the post of Patrick, this solved the issue.
- Add `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >` in the `<html>` tag
- Add `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` to remove the auto hyperlink.

Reference: [Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

Answer (score 0):

could you try to uninstall the Skype "Click-to-Call" add-on?

Comment: There is no Skype "Click-to-Call" add-on installed.