# Billion number on Edge turns into a clickable ip

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I use the " . " as thousand separator, so when i need to put some billion number on chrome,fox or IE it works fine, but on Edge the browser turns the text on a link.

You can test this making a simple html and opening on diferent browsers.

```
<body>
    <label>1,999,999,999</label>
    <br>
    <label>1.100.100.000</label>
</body>
```

How can i avoid this on Edge?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: on Microsoft Edge this text '1.100.100.000' turns into a link, on other browsers its just a normal text. How can i avoid this on Edge?

Comment: Please include a specific question in your next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link isn't a clickable IP, but interpreted as a phone number.

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867199/2897426 provides a way to disable automatic phone number detection, by adding the following meta tag to the `<head>` of your html file:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

See the linked answer for further links.